# not able to make async request using aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I have following python api function which takes some time to give output. its api endpoint is abc/abcd. when i hit that api endpoint simultaneously from multiple ip's it does not give next output till previous request is not complete. I am using aiohttp. I api should answer many requests at the same time

```
async def Logistic(request):
    container_id = request.query['container_id']
    company = request.query['company']
    data = mysqlcon("SELECT date,moves,location,vessel,voyage,current_status FROM container_status WHERE date_current in (SELECT max(date_current) FROM container_status) and company_id={0}".format(container_id),"rpa")
    a = {"Result":[]}
    if data == ():
        pass
    else:
        for i in data:
            a["Result"].append(i)
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(a),headers={'ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN':'*'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move all database access code (`SELECT ...` execution and iteration over returned result) into a separate function and run it in thread pool:

```
def sync_db_request(container_id):
    data = mysqlcon("SELECT date,moves,location,vessel,voyage,current_status FROM container_status WHERE date_current in (SELECT max(date_current) FROM container_status) and company_id={0}".format(container_id),"rpa")
    a = {"Result":[]}
    if data == ():
        pass
    else:
        for i in data:
            a["Result"].append(i)
    return a

async def Logistic(request):
    container_id = request.query['container_id']
    company = request.query['company']
    a = await request.loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_db_request, container_id)
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(a),headers={'ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN':'*'})
```

Comment: i will try your solution and get back to you

Comment: Its working thanks, Can you give me api authentication example using public key and private key